# Showing Images using XF ImagePicker Without Putting Image in Resources

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms prerelease they have released a media picker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android

This is obviously a great addition and the fact that you don't have to use any 3rd party-library is great!

I'm creating an event management app - in the app the user can select an image for the event and be able to see it.

Here is my code:

```
public async void OnSelectPhotoCommand()
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
            await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
        }

        async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
        {
            var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
            using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
            using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile)) { await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream); }

            ImagePath = newFile;
        }
```

The problem is the image is not showing or appearing whatsoever - I've tried to modify my code and debug it but I am unable to locate the source of the problem.

I want the user to be actually able to see the image - but I am unsure on how to do that using the MediaPicker without putting it in the Android Resources folder?

Thank you,

tommy

Comment: try using AppDataDirectory instead of CacheDirectory

Comment: Tried that and still didn't work @Jason

Answer (score 0):

From the xamarin essentials documentation be sure to be running it from the UI Thread.

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
    OnSelectPhotoCommand();
});
```